# How to keep a timer counting when app reach background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I prepared a CountDown timer for Pomodoro technique. I would like to know how don't pause the app when it reach a background. I have a method which update UILabel from 20min to 0 by 1sec. When Timer reach 0 it should play the sound and vibrate device. All works fine when app is launched in foreground, but how to do it at background? Is it possible to track timer change when app is in background mode?

BR
iMat

Comment: I think it would be best to use a local notification for this. Your app will only get a short amount of CPU time when backgrounded and will then be suspended.

Answer (score 1):

- Invalidate the timer when the app goes to background. Store the remaining time `remainingTime` and current time `backgroundTime`. (You can get the current time using `Date()`)
- Compare the current time `backToForegroundTime` when the app comes back with `backgroundTime`. Subtract them to get the time elapsed `timeElapsed`.
- If `timeElapsed` is less than the `remainingTime`, subtract that amount from `remainingTime` and create the timer again with the new duration.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. A timer on a VC will not continue to run when the app is in the background because it goes into suspended mode.

You could schedule a local notification to fire when the app is in the background, but as far as updating the UI label, you'll have to update that when the user comes back into the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my approach from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ZalyalovIldar/a02080141ded4f9de29bd94bc5e7444c). Just create repeating timer and update what ever you want in repeating block, and handle timer finishing in other block on main queue or background queue! 
Glad to help with questions!

Answer (score 0):

Apple has defined a specific set of tasks, an app can perform when in background.
Running a timer, unfortunately, is not one of them.
Read [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) section of app programming guide for more details.

Most apps, intending to continue to execute code in background, implement one of the **allowed** [long running background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4), even if it is not required for your apps actual functionality, and use them to execute their code. 
But be ware, you will be doing something apple specifically asks you not to do. This could result in app store rejection if found.